# Converting datatype Char to Nvarchar

Tags: sql, char, sql-server-2012, nvarchar

I am currently trying to convert all columns in all tables of my database from char to nvarchar in SQL server 2012.

the query I am trying to run is

```
select cast((select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where DATA_TYPE = 'char') as nvarchar(MAX))
```

Not sure if I should be changing the data type through INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but I found this to be the best way to grab the datatype.

the error I am currently getting is:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this or a way around this error, as it seems it doesn't like me changing datatypes to multiple rows at the same time.

Comment: looks like function cast works with single fields, not multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is a good way to determine what columns need to be converted,

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'CHAR';
```

But it can't be used to directly change a column's data type. [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) is used to modify column data types:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(50);
```

While you're at it, avoid using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` unless it's absolutely necessary. Make sure your data types are sized specifically for the attribute. If your `CHAR` columns are already sized correctly, use the following script to **generate** the `ALTER TABLE` statements:

```
SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' +
        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' +
        QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +
        ' ALTER COLUMN ' +
        QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) +
        ' NVARCHAR(' +
        CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(4)) + ');'
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   DATA_TYPE = 'char';
```

Keep in mind that this only generates the ALTER TABLE statements, you'll need to copy the results and execute in a new tab to change the data types.

Comment: Just a quick one I'm getting the confirmation from that query that 9365 rows have been changed, but when looking at the tables the data_type still hasn't changed. is this query just showing the changes that will be effected and I need to put update instead of select or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This only generates the required ALTER TABLE statements. Copy results to a new window and execute to change data types. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You are getting the error because the select returns more than one row and you are trying to cast to nvarchar(MAX) all the column_name. Any subquery that you might need to do it in the future must only return one row.

```
select cast((select top 1 COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where DATA_TYPE = 'char') as nvarchar(MAX))
```

This will fix the error, but that is not what you are trying to do.

To update all the columns you need  to do something based on the following command:

> ALTER TABLE {TableName} ALTER COLUMN {ColumnName} NVARCHAR(size)

What you could do is to get the table_name and column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and build a dynamic script to update all the columns in the database from char to nvarchar.